# Multiple proxy_pass destination for multiple domain name

Tags: django, apache, nginx

What I want to do is like this,

Change the destination of proxy depending on domain name.

However it shows the error

`a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:8090 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:7`

default.conf is here

```
server{

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
     server_name exmaple.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8021/;
        include     /var/www/html/exmaple/current/uwsgi_params;
    }
}

server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name exmaple2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8022/;
        include     /var/www/html/exmaple2/current/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I should not duplicate the server delective.

However how can I use multiple proxy_pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `default_server` from the first or the second server config.